# JLabel.setText() relocates all labels in mousewheelevent

Tags: java, swing, location, jlabel, settext

EDIT: leaving short code which shows issue:
Then label.setText("") is called and it has to change the text, i.e. scaler overcame 50 barrier the label dissapears for the mousewheelevent -> re-emerges on next event. Also a problem of the label not being present on the Load-up.
In actual program labels stack together in 1 spot if any of them has .setText() changing value or .setVisible changing (These two methods I need to be able to use without affecting labels positioning)

```
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
public class brokenLabel extends JFrame
{
private JLayeredPane layerPane;
private JPanel breakingLabelPanel = new JPanel();
private JLabel label;
private int scaler = 50;
private int xstart = 200;
private int ystart = 200;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
brokenLabel program = new brokenLabel();
}
public brokenLabel() 
{
// Frame setup used on the program
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is a slideshow");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
layerPane = new JLayeredPane();
frame.setContentPane(layerPane);        
// Panel used (it's similar to what's added on the actual program)
breakingLabelPanel.setOpaque(true);
breakingLabelPanel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(breakingLabelPanel));
breakingLabelPanel.setVisible(true);
breakingLabelPanel.setSize(getMaximumSize());
breakingLabelPanel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener(){
    @Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent arg0) 
{       
    if (scaler > 5 || arg0.getWheelRotation() < 0)
        scaler = scaler - 5*arg0.getWheelRotation();
    setTexts();
}
});
//The testing label
label = new JLabel(new String("1"));
label.setLocation(xstart , ystart);
breakingLabelPanel.add(label);
frame.add(breakingLabelPanel,layerPane);        
frame.setVisible(true);
//revalidate and repaint don't help make label visible on load-up
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
}

public void setTexts(){
label.setLocation(xstart + scaler,ystart + 25);
if(scaler < 50)
{
    label.setText("1");
}
else 
{
    label.setText("2");
}
}
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A quick tip: Try to show a _minimum_ working example. In your case, that would mean, remove all code that can be removed while still demonstrating the problem. You might also try to cut down on the description of the problem. Here's why: a) less to read -> easier to digest, more people will be able/willing to help b) while you shorten, you get a crisper idea of where the problem sits, c) the question might become more reusable as we move from a very special to a more general problem

Comment: If anyone runs into a similar kind of problem -> just use JTextField rather than JLabel . They work perfectly fine